# What is this disease on my Basil?

Tags: herbs, diseases, basil

I've planted Basil (from a pot) outside and it's been very wet in the last few weeks. The plant has now got these grey spots on it. What is wrong with it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is leafspot, or pseudomonas cichorii. It is a bacteria that lives in the soil and infects the plant when soil is splashed onto the leaves

There is no cure for bacterial leaf spot for homeowners. Growers could use streptomycin or copper maneb but I would not use these for something I was going to eat.

Here are some recommendations:

- Minimize the damage by making sure that your basil plants have plenty of air circulation and that they are watered in a way so that the soil is not splashed onto the leaves.
- Remove all infected leaves as well.
- There appears to be a link to growing at cool moist temperatures.  Try to provide a sunnier, drier environment.

Comment: A grassy mulch can help by reducing splash.  But if it's already too wet in general, it may not be a good idea.