# Basil: cold or disease?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, basil

A few days ago I put my basil outside. In a couple of days, the temperature fell considerably, and I think it got a shock, despite moving it back inside as soon as I could. I think this is the reason, however, it could also be a disease. Can you say if it's one or the other? The leaves are yellowish and broken, with the borders of the cuts greyish or brownish. In addition, there are slight pits on both surfaces of the leaf, either brown or grey.

[image]

Comment: Related: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3968/what-is-this-disease-on-my-basil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basil is not very cold hardy and damage from just a touch of frost looks like this. Once a plant is weakened in cool damp weather the usual bacterial suspects move in.

I would pick off the damaged leaves and hope for warmer sunnier weather.

Comment: +1 probably cold+wet, but doesn't sound like OP hardened the basil off before leaving it outside.

Comment: @Grady: hardened?

Comment: seedlings grown indoors are not used to the intensity of sunlight.  You have to put them out under shade for a week or so to let them adjust.

Comment: @kevinsky: They are not seedlings, and they are in partial shade already. I don't have full sun, unfortunately.

Comment: @StefanoBorini: [This answer](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/3576/51) talks about hardening off seedlings; which will apply to some extent to your basil since it's not used to being outside.